share display without network connection
I want to share the screen with another monitor or PC without any network connection (there may be a hardware connection). I am using Ubuntu 22.04 emmc khadas vim4. There is no screen mirroring feature in vim4. I need to achieve this with something. I thought about using GNOME Remote Desktop, but I guess it needs to be on the same network. I will definitely not have an internet connection. How do I solve this? If anyone has knowledge, can you please guide?
share the screen with another monitor

Please describe more clearly what you are trying to achieve. "share the screen with another monitor or PC" is unclear.

share the screen with another monitor

If by "share the screen" you mean "view the screen" on another PC, you may want to look into e.g. HDMI capture cards and HDMI splitters as an option to send the physical display signal to your other PC where you can use tools like OBS Studio, or VLC to view the video stream.
The question is however ambiguous. If you want the above, but also e.g. sharing your keyboard and mouse you might want to look into USB switches to switch where your keyboard+mouse are connected to quickly, or full on KVM switches which include switching video output to your display. Depending on exactly why you want to avoid networking maybe a tool like PiKVM may be what you're looking for.

I'm using khadas vim4 and I'm using ubuntu. Normally, PCs have a mirror feature, in the settings -> display section of Khadas, the mirror feature appears to be available due to Ubuntu, but this feature cannot be used in Khadas Vim4. so it doesn't work. I need a software that will provide this feature or something that will change the settings in Ubuntu. When you plug in HDMI, the screen is expanded. I cannot see the same screen on both monitors. What I want is to see the same screen.
